# Calling Related Entries using the Element API

Tags: plugin-elementapi

I have two sections, each with a single entry type:

- Sites
- Locations

In the Locations entry type I have a Entries field called Site that you can use to relate a Location to a Site entry.

My questions is: how do I show which locations were related to a Site entry when using the Element API? I'd like to display it as an array when using a sites/.json endpoint.

This is what I've tried, but it breaks the endpoint:

```
'v1/sites/<entryId:\d+>.json' => function($entryId) {
  return [
    'elementType' => 'Entry',
    'criteria' => ['id' => $entryId],
    'first' => true,
    'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {
      $locations = $entry->getChildren()->type('locations')->find();
      foreach ($locations as $location) {
        $locationsInfo[] = [
          'name' => $location->title
        ];
      }

      return [
        'id' => $entry->id,
        'name' => $entry->title,
        'tagline' => $entry->tagline,
        'about' => $entry->about->getParsedContent(),
        'locations' => $locationsInfo,
        'jsonUrl' => UrlHelper::getUrl("v1/sites/{$entry->id}.json")
      ];
    },
  ];
},
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You’d do this with a brand new element query using the [relatedTo](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#relatedTo) param.

Craft 2:

```php
// This is the PHP equivalent of typing `craft.entries()` in a template:
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);

// Only fetch Location entries that are related to the Site entry:
$criteria->section = 'locations';
$criteria->relatedTo = ['targetElement' => $entry];

$locations = $criteria->find();
```

Craft 3:

```php
// This is the PHP equivalent of typing `craft.entries()` in a template:
$query = \craft\elements\Entry::find();

// Only fetch Location entries that are related to the Site entry:
$query->section('locations');
$query->relatedTo(['targetElement' => $entry]);

$locations = $query->all();
```

Comment: Looks like this broke in the updated version we're using for Craft 3. Getting a _Call to undefined function craft()_ error when loading up the endpoint.

Comment: @Roger you might want to read the documentation  https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/master/en/element-queries.md you'll find many things you need to know for Craft 3 but if you are going to create a more complex site (with custom plugins) you must go through the source code or analyze other plugins in order to use everything properly